# how does couchdb 2.1 views queries with limit on cluster works?

Tags: range, couchdb, view, cluster-computing

I'm just wondering how does a cluster of couchdb operates on range query with limits.
suppose i'm querying startKey="abc" endKey="xyz" limit=10
what happens on each node? is it fetching documents then sending just top 10 to query server?
or it sends all data and lets query server do the job of limiting and sorting?

thanks